# Translate Excel formula to be used in field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, excel, python-parser

I have a series of equations to create corner points to make rotated polygons based on angles in the attribute table, but I have created it in excel and can't figure out the syntax to get it to work properly in the field calculator.  I have 8 different trigonometric formulas to create XY coordinates for the 4 corner points.  One of them is as follows:

```
=COS(ATAN(1500/2250)+RADIANS(MOD(360-([Angle]+270),360)))*(SQRT((1500^2)+(2250^2)))+[X]
```

Once I understand the syntax for one, I should be able to use it for the other 7 formulas, even though they vary slightly.
Can anyone advise the best way to use this formula in field calculator?
Thanks.

**Edit**, after receiving @Paul's answer:

I figured out the correct syntax of some of the other ones, but two of them are still giving me trouble.  One is producing a different result than Excel and one is saying that the syntax is incorrect.

```
=COS(RADIANS(270)-ATAN(750/1500)+RADIANS(MOD(360-([A]+270),360)))*SQRT((1500^2)+(750^2))+[X]

=COS(-ATAN(1500/2250)+RADIANS(MOD(360-([A]+270),360)))*SQRT((1500^2)+(2250^2))+[X]
```

I think it has to do with the negative signs and me probably putting them in the wrong spot...

Comment: Are `Angle` and `X` your only two variables?

Comment: @Paul yeah.  i'm going to have to do it for Y, too, but that will be in a separate field.  everything else is just the calculation.

Answer (score 10):

All of the trigonometric functions you need are in the [math](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) module. I presume you'll want [atan2()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2) which is the equivalent of atan(y/x). For the mod function, you'll need to use the percent symbol.

Each function also has a simplified version (a) since you are calculating some constants. They're identical functions but will be faster.

Parser:

```py
Python
```

Codeblock:

```py
from math import cos, atan2, radians, sqrt
from math import cos, radians #Use this for simplified functions as others aren't needed.

def trigfunc1(angle, x):
    return cos(atan2(1500,2250) + radians((360-(angle+270))%360)) * sqrt(1500**2+2250**2) + x

def trigfunc1a(angle, x):
    return cos(0.5880026035475675 + radians((90-angle)%360)) * 2704.163456597992 + x

def trigfunc2(a, x):
    return cos(radians(270) - atan2(750,1500) + radians((360-(a+270)%360))) * sqrt(1500**2+750**2) + x

def trigfunc2a(a, x):
    return cos(4.2487413713838835 + radians((90-a)%360)) * 1677.0509831248423 + x

def trigfunc3(a, x):
    return cos(-atan2(1500,2250) + radians((360-(a+270)%360))) * sqrt((1500**2)+(2250**2)) + x

def trigfunc3a(a, x):
    return cos(-0.5880026035475675 + radians((90-a)%360)) * 2704.163456597992 + x
```

Expression:

```py
trigfunc1(!Angle!, !X!)
trigfunc2(!A!, !X!)
trigfunc3(!A!, !X!)
```

Comment: Ahh!  Perfect!  Thank you so much!  The only thing is the first x in (x+270) actually needed to be angle, but with that change it works perfectly.  I probably should consider learning python one of these days...

Comment: @katzendoodle, yeah I just noticed that. Fixed, thanks. If you have issues with the other formulas, you can edit them into your post and drop me a comment here.

Comment: I posted two other formulas because they were giving me trouble...I got all of the other ones, though.  Thanks.

Comment: @katzendoodle, those should work.